# How to check if one HTTP client is still connected to the server in asp.net core?

Tags: http, asp.net-core, .net-core, httpclient, asp.net-core-1.1

I wanna know if there is a way to check if one client is still connected to asp.net core server?

If I understand well, in the standard asp.net we can do this using [this property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected(v=vs.110).aspx), and I'm asking if we can do so in asp.net core?

Comment: You can check the RequestAborted cancellation token.

Comment: it workerd, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by @Tratcher, we can check the RequestAborted cancellation token.